# How to fix apt after doing easy_install pip?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python, pip

I ran into the following error while using pip: "[pip stops with ImportError for request-Modul](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1306991)"

I read on a forum that an easy solution was to just **apt-get remove pip** and then to do **easy_install pip**. I did this, and it did indeed make pip start working again.

However, I later read that using easy_install is a bad idea and can break apt's package management. So my question is, how do I "undo" whatever easy_install did and get apt to manage pip properly again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you have to do:**
Reinstall the `python-pip` package with `apt` and afterwards upgrade your `pip` to the latest version with `pip` itself or `easy_install` if it is broken.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade pip || sudo easy_install --upgrade pip
```

---

**Why you should do that:**
`apt` only installs packages it finds in your installed repositories, but the python packages in the official repositories are incredibly outdated! However, some packages you might install in the future may list `python-pip` as dependency and and require that package to be installed. They won't recognize it if you installed it without `apt`. Also, the `man` command does not work for `pip` then as only `apt` creates a manpage for it, `easy_install` does not.

`easy_install` and `pip` however don't fetch their packages from any repository, but from PyPI (Python Package Index), which always holds the latest available versions.

So my suggestion is to use `pip` instead of `apt` to update python packages if you want current versions. `easy_install` is the ancestor of `pip` and should usually be avoided and replaced by `pip`, but as long as it's broken, you have to use it. You could also do a `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` to get the latest `pip` version without `easy_install`.

If you don't have the `pip` package installed by `apt`, then just do it additionally. I did not remove `python-pip` with `apt` before upgrading it with `pip` or `easy_install` and it also works. As `apt` installs the old `pip` version in `/usr/bin` and `pip`/`easy_install` use the directory `/usr/local/bin`, which has the higher priority, a plain call to `pip` without giving an explicit directory always runs the newer version, if more than one is installed.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Just to be clear though, you say that after I `apt-get install python-pip`, that I should use `pip` to update itself from then on. Will `apt` conflict with this later when I do `apt-get upgrade`, or should it be fine since the `pip install --upgrade pip` version will be later than the `apt` version?

Comment: The old repository (apt) `pip` is installed in `/usr/bin/` and the new pip/easy_install `pip` is located in `/usr/local/bin`, which is the path with higher priority and therefore, the new pip gets executed when you just type `pip` without an explicit directory. So both `pip` versions exist in parallel without disturbing each other. - I edited my answer to include this and correct my previous inaccuracy.